# Include directory in VS 2003

Tags: visual-studio, include

Where is the setting in Visual Studio 2003 to set the include path for individual projects?  I know about the VC Directories option in Tools>Options but that is machine specific and won't help when I hand this off to other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I don't see that option.  I ended up opening the vcproj file in jedit and writing it in.

[idontknow http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/1128/idontknowmanln2.jpg](http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/1128/idontknowmanln2.jpg)

Comment: Is that the property page for the solution or the project?

Comment: For the project.  I think this ended up being the result of not restarting the machine after installing VS2003.